# How to get the following output?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment, align, sourcecode

How to get the following output (without manually adding space)? I guess I should use the align environment but I can't get the domain and the codomain centered with the respective elements in the second line. I need a general algorithm, which I would use whenever I need to define a map.
[image]

Notice how there are three separate centered pieces, i.e. the domain with its elements, the arrows and the codomain with the images of the map.

Comment: Please provide some compilable code to play with. Show us, what you've got so far

Comment: This output can be produced with `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{rccc}
\Phi : & \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} & \longrightarrow &
\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^3\\
& (u,v) & \longmapsto & (e^{iu},v)=(\cos u,\sin u,v)
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}`. The question is whether one would like to use such notation.

Comment: For my humble opinion your image can be created with different ways.

Comment: Your title is not really well chosen...

Answer (score 2):

I don't find this particularly appealing, but here it is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\R}{\numberset{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\numberset{C}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% disable standard intercolumn spaces
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% more room between rows
\begin{array}{r c >{{}}c<{{}} c}
\Phi\colon{} & \R\times\R & \longrightarrow & \C\times\R=\R^3 \\
             & (u,v)      & \longmapsto     & (e^{iu},v)=(\cos u,\sin u,v)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly different version with `l` for the last column:

```latex
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% disable standard intercolumn spaces
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% more room between rows
\begin{array}{r c >{{}}c<{{}} l}
\Phi\colon{} & \R\times\R & \longrightarrow & \C\times\R=\R^3 \\
             & (u,v)      & \longmapsto     & (e^{iu},v)=(\cos u,\sin u,v)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not reproduce the output precisely because you do `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}` and all these things. [This code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521500/how-to-get-the-following-output#comment1318740_521500) does.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Do you think I’m not able to reproduce that output and I didn’t ponder whether to persist in error or to suggest a typographically sounder representation?

Comment: The question was to reproduce the output. I also remarked that one may not want to reproduce the output. All I am saying is ... OK, just read above...

Answer (score 2):

You also can do it with package `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\R}{\numberset{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\numberset{C}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Phi\colon\eqmathbox[L]{\R\times\R} & \longrightarrow \eqmathbox[R]{\C\times\R=\R^3} \\
\eqmathbox[L]{(u,v)} & \longmapsto \eqmathbox[R]{(e^{iu},v)=(\cos u,\sin u,v)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]